# regex to extract 5 words after the match

Tags: android, regex

I'm trying to create a regex in my app and having trouble understanding it. I've created one regex but still, I want it to be modified to do not match specific things. I need to create regex for both iOS and Android.

This is my regex

```
(?:rahul[\s"'?.!:s()\{\}])
```

This is my test string

```
rahul hello rahul! vyas and rahul? and rahul. and rahul: and rahul and rahul( and rahul) and rahul{ rahul.shiv  rahuls vyas rips rahul!!
```

This is the site I'm using to create the regex
[Regex Creator](https://regex101.com/r/1FQ8eq/1/)

What I actually want to match is if user type word rahul then it should match all rahul words including punctuations or if the word has s in it in the end. It should not select rahul.shiv.

Also is it possible to extract 5 words after the match and before the match. lets assume the word is in the middle of the sentence and I need to extract 5 words as prefix of the match and 5 words as suffix of the match. If anyone knows how to create this regex kindly answer the question with explanation.

Update -
Screenshot for above matches
[image]

Update 2 for Second regex demo
[image]

The third capture group is only matching 2 words instead of 5 words.

Comment: Can you show your expected matches from above text?

Comment: sure adding screenshot. You can also try on the website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For finding all the matches for your search word use:

```sh
\brahuls?[^\s\w]*(?=\s|$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XzRgh5/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b`; Word boundary
- `rahuls?`: Search word followed by an optional `s`
- `[^\s\w]*`: Match 0 or more non-whitespace non-word characters
- `(?=\s|$)`: Must be followed by a whitespace or end of line

---

For allowing up to 5 words before and after the match use this regex with **3 capture groups**:

```
(\b(?:\S+\s+){0,5}?)(\brahuls?[^\s\w]*(?=\s|$))(?=((?:\s+\S+){0,5}))
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/CWZEXG/3)

- `(\b(?:\S+\s+){0,5}?)`: Capture group #1 to *lazily* match 0 to 5 words before search word
- `(\brahuls?[^\s\w]*(?=\s|$))`: Capture group #2 to match search word as per regex above
- `(?=((?:\s+\S+){0,5}))`: Capture group #3 to match 0 ot 5 words after the search word. Please note that this group is inside a lookahead to allow us to match overlapping matches

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation anubhava. Now only thing I'm missing here is the first expression doesn't match the word rahuls. I want to match plurals or if it's not possible then only character s if it exists after the word. Also is it possible to only match 1 character ? In the current expression you have given it matches rahul!!

Comment: how about this expression 

\brahul[s]|rahul[^\s\w]*(?=\s|$)

Comment: one more question @anubhava what If I only want to match punctuation characters followed by word e.g rahul! and rahul? like these

Comment: Also, I didn't understand the second reg ex demo. How we will extract 5 words before and after in JAVA?

Comment: Yeah, I understood now. Thanks for your valuable time. My doubt was how to extract matched group of 5 words from matcher?

Comment: The second example is somehow not working in the demo

Comment: capture group #3 is not working. Updated the original post with screenshot

Comment: I have tried the same regex demo which you've provided. I just want to match the first occurrence of the word and then 5 words on both side even if the 5 words includes the same word from the match

Comment: It's like shortening a paragraph user will search a word and when the regex finds the first occurrence of the word it will. match the word even if it has 's' or 'punctuations' and then 5 words before and after the match

Comment: I used this string for test

rahul hello rahul! vyas and rahul? and rahul. and rahul: and rahul and rahul( and rahul) and rahul{ rahul.shiv  rahuls vyas rips rahul!!

Comment: Ok check this demo: https://regex101.com/r/CWZEXG/3

Comment: can you update your answer with the final regex with an explanation?

Comment: @RahulVyas: I had already updated answer with latest regex and demo link.